# Shopware 6.5 Vietnamese as System Default Language

Tags: shopware, shopware6

i would like to setup a new shop with Vietnamese as default language.
While going through the setup, i can only choose one of the following languages:

- German
- English (United Kingdom)
- English (United States of America)
- Czech
- Spanish
- French
- Italian
- Dutch
- Polish
- Portuguese
- Swedish
- Danish
- Norwegian

Is it not possible, to use Vietnamese as default language?

Comment: Remark: On https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/extensions/language-pack it says "On the one hand, you can obtain and configure the extension directly during the installation of Shopware in the initial setup wizard." - but that does not seem to refer to the installer where the initial language is chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `system:configure-shop` [console command](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/shopware-cli) to change the default language after the initial setup:

```
bin/console system:configure-shop --shop-locale vi-VN
```

However definitely make a backup of your database beforehand. As the command itself states:

> Changing the shops default locale after the fact can be destructive.